# Querying firebase firestore in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to using firestore and firebase cloud functions generally and I want to create a few routes for querying firestore however I'm really stuck and I do not know where is the problem.
Code:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const firebase = require('firebase-admin');


    firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
    let db = firebase.firestore();
    const app = express();
    const main = express();

    main.use('/api/v1', app);
    main.use(bodyParser.json());
    main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    exports.webapi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

    app.get('/warmup', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Warming up friend.');                             
    //This one works fine
    });

    //Register user
    app.post('/user/register',(req,res)=>{
    try{
    db.collection('users').doc('fbusers').set({     //Does not work , 
    Name: 'omar',
    phone : '123213123',
    });
    }
    catch(e){
     console.log(e);
    }
     });
```

When I try to insert any values into firestore it does not respond
please acknowledge that I'm using postman to test and checking firestore accordingly , and I think the firebase setup itself is okay

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not doing some compute in the middle, how about checking firestore client side sdk documentation?

[firestore quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should await that db set your content (set return a promise with the writeTime)

```
   //Register user
    app.post('/user/register',async (req,res)=>{
      try{
        await db.collection('users').doc('fbusers').set({     //Does not work , 
          Name: 'omar',
          phone : '123213123',
        });
        res.send("Register user completed"); 
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send(e);
      }
    });
```